# IsAssignableFrom on GenericType

Tags: c#, reflection

Not sure if I can do this or not, but I'm trying to see if a type inherits from another type with a generic constraint.

Here is the class I want to find:

```
public class WorkoutCommentStreamMap : ClassMapping<WorkoutCommentStream>...
```

And here is the test

```
var inheritableType = typeof(NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Conformist.ClassMapping<>);
var isMappedObject = inheritableType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(WorkoutCommentStreamMap));
```

If I change the first line to below, it works.  But that defeats the purpose of my example.  My fallback work around is to put a custom, non-generic, interface on all the objects I want to find and use the same call.

```
var inheritableType = typeof(NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Conformist.ClassMapping<WorkoutCommentStream>);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is not an inheritance relationship between a generic type definition and a closed generic type. Therefore, `IsAssignableFrom` will not work.

However, I use this little extension method to achieve what your after:

```
public static bool IsGenericTypeOf(this Type t, Type genericDefinition)
{
    Type[] parameters = null;
    return IsGenericTypeOf(t, genericDefinition, out parameters);
}

public static bool IsGenericTypeOf(this Type t, Type genericDefinition, out Type[] genericParameters)
{
    genericParameters = new Type[] { };
    if (!genericDefinition.IsGenericType)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var isMatch = t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericDefinition.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    if (!isMatch && t.BaseType != null)
    {
        isMatch = IsGenericTypeOf(t.BaseType, genericDefinition, out genericParameters);
    }
    if (!isMatch && genericDefinition.IsInterface && t.GetInterfaces().Any())
    {
        foreach (var i in t.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (i.IsGenericTypeOf(genericDefinition, out genericParameters))
            {
                isMatch = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isMatch && !genericParameters.Any())
    {
        genericParameters = t.GetGenericArguments();
    }
    return isMatch;
}
```

With sample usage:

```
Nullable<int> value = 9;
Assert.IsTrue(value.GetType().IsGenericTypeOf(typeof(Nullable<>)));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `BaseType`, `IsGenericType` and `GetGenericTypeDefinition` to recurse up the hierarchy and try to find it:

```
public bool IsClassMapping(Type t)
{
    while (t != null)
    {
        if (t.IsGenericType &&
            t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ClassMapping<>))
        {
            return true;
        }
        t = t.BaseType;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do will not work, and its called out explicitly in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) why:

> A generic type definition is not assignable from a closed constructed
>   type. That is, you cannot assign the closed constructed type
>   `MyGenericList<int>` to a variable of type `MyGenericList<T>`

`IsAssignableFrom` seems like overkill here; can you just use `BaseType` to check for a matching type?

Comment: @Trent: Note that you'll need to go up the hierarchy if you want to include subclasses of `WorkoutCommentStreamMap` etc.

Comment: @Reddog had the best answer.  I can roll than into my linq query and its still pretty.

Answer (score 1):

There is never an inheritance relation between `MyType<>`, `MyType<T>` and `MyType<ConcreteType>`! In consequence, they will never be assignment compatible.

An exception are interface types having generic parameters with an `in` or `out` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help?

```
    public static bool IsConcreteGenericOf(this Type type, Type openGeneric)
    {
        if (!type.IsGenericType)
            return false;
        if (!openGeneric.IsGenericType)
            return false;
        if (!openGeneric.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            return false;

        return type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == openGeneric;
    }
```

Sorta simlar to Jon Skeet's answer, he beat me to it.

Comment: With 400k+ I think Skeet beats alot of people to it